# How to check dmark records on an email source?

Tags: linux, email

How can I check an email against its dmarc signature ? ie, check that the dmarc signature associated with the email is VALID.

I am a Ubuntu user, I am aware of the dkimpy package allowing this for dkim (dkimverify < email.eml) and ideally would like to do a simple dmarcverify < email.eml or similar functionality, to check the DMARC (not dkim) signature is valid.

Google search has not led me anywhere (or I missed the point maybe... i am not expert in that area).

Thanks.
Christophe

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note : this question has been closed redirecting here
https://superuser.com/questions/1042496/linux-tool-to-check-dkim-signed-emails
which addresses dkim ONLY, hence it does NOT answer current question.

The current question is about dmarc, NOT dkim.
Please reopen, or answer or point to the REAL answer if you know it.

Comment: Note : this question has been closed redirecting here
https://superuser.com/questions/1042496/linux-tool-to-check-dkim-signed-emails
which addresses ONLY dkim checking, hence it does NOT answer current question which queries how to check dmarc, not dkim. I have edited the current question hopefully making it a bit clearer. 

The current question is about dmarc, NOT dkim.
Please reopen, or answer or point to the REAL answer if you know it.